# regex ensure string starts and ends with digits

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I write a regular expression for use in JavaScript that'll ensure the first and last characters of a string are always digits?

```
r = /\D+/g;
var s = "l10ddd31ddd5705ddd";
var o = r.test(s);
console.log(o);
```

So, `1KJ25LP3665` would return true, while `K12M25XC5750` would return false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a regex like below:

```
 /^\d(.*\d)?$/
```

- The `^` to begin match from start of the string and `$` to continue match till end of the string.
- `\d` to match a digit at the beginning and the end.
- `.*` to match zero or more characters in between.
- We make the group `1` => `(.*\d)` optional with the `?` metacharacter to optionally match zero or more characters ending with the digit till the end of the string. This would help if the string has only a single digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(s.matches("\\d.*\\d"))
{
// Do what you want once both start and ending characters are digits 
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

This solution achieves the same result without a Regex. It also takes care of empty strings or strings with only one character.

```
function startsAndEndsWithDigits(string) 
{
    if(string.length>0)//if string is not empty
    {
        var firstChar = string.split('')[0];//get the first charcter of the string
        var lastChar  = string.split('')[string.length -1];//get the last charcter of the string
        if(firstChar.length>0 && lastChar.length>0)
        {   //if first and last charcters are numbers, return true. Otherwise return false.
            return !isNaN(firstChar) && !isNaN(lastChar);
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Usage example:

```
startsAndEndsWithDigits('1KJ25LP3665'); //returns true 
startsAndEndsWithDigits('K12M25XC5750');//returns false
startsAndEndsWithDigits('');            //returns false
startsAndEndsWithDigits('a');           //returns false 
startsAndEndsWithDigits('7');           //returns true
```